# i386 Keyboard interrupt not triggering after initialise GDT and IDT, setup interrupt handlers etc

Tags: x86, interrupt, osdev

I am learning to develop a small os, it now can initialise GDT, IDT, display some text at screen, I am now trying to get keyboard interrupt, the example code I got from 30days diy OS by OSASK on day6 harib03e works. But my implementation not working, source code is at
https://github.com/Lewis-Liu-1/myos/tree/main/day6/daye.

From web search, I realise I only load GDT, IDT, load kernel, not configuring keyboard, to enable PS/2 interrupt somehow. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: A quick look at int.c has this: `outb(PIC0_IMR, 0xfb); /* 11111011 PIC1ÈOÍSÄÖ~ */` . Keyboard is interrupt 1 but you have bit 1 set to 1 which means no interrupt. Maybe you meant to use 0xfd which would 11111101 where bit 1 is 0 enabling that interrupt? Or do you clear that bit somewhere else?

Comment: As well, some one will probably point out that this question is not a good fit for Stackoverflow since the code resides entirely on an external site and the question itself lacks any detail to help. You might want to ask on the osdev forum at https://forum.osdev.org/

Comment: Check out this page https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller It has some detailed steps for initializing a PS2 Controller